# Changing df of integers to num doesn't work

Tags: r

I'm a newbie in R and don't have much experience with solving errors, so one more time I need help. I have a data frame named *n_occur* that has 2 columns - number and freq. Both values are integers. I wanted to get the histogram, but I got the error: `argument x must be numeric`, so I wanted to change both columns into num.
Firstly I tried with the simplest way:

```
n_occur[,] = as.numeric(as.character(n_occur[,]))
```

but as a result all values changed into NA. So after searching on stack, I decided to use this formula:

```
indx <- sapply(n_occur, is.factor)
n_occur[indx] <- lapply(n_occur[indx], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

and nothing changed, I still have integers and hist still doesn't work. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone needs it in future, I solved the problem with `mutate` from dplyr:

```
n_occur <- mutate(n_occur, freq=as.numeric(freq))
```

for both columns separately. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really have to do that, just supply the function with the actual columns instead of the entire dataframe. For example:

```
n_occur = data.frame(
  number = sample(as.integer(1:10), 10, TRUE),
  freq = sample(as.integer(0:10), 10, TRUE)
)
str(n_occur)

'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ number: int  9 8 8 5 6 7 8 10 3 4
 $ freq  : int  0 9 2 0 4 10 7 2 7 9

hist(n_occur$number) # works 
hist(n_occur$freq) # works
plot(n_occur$number, n_occur$freq, type = 'h') # works
hist(n_occur) # fails since it is the whole dataframe
```

Also if you still want to do that, this converts a factor to numeric:

```
as.numeric(factor(1:10))
```